# 'object' does not contain a definition for 'CountryName'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to pass data using ViewBag.Unions. I get data at controller, but when i foreach loop in view it says 'object' does not contain a definition for 'CountryName'.I give the full code from controller and view. I can not solve this problem.

Controller

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {



            List<Country> listCountry = _db.Countries.ToList();
            ViewBag.Countries = listCountry;

            ViewBag.Unions = (from unon in _db.Unions
                              join upz in _db.Upazilas on unon.UpazilaId equals upz.UpazilaId
                              join dic in _db.Districts on upz.DistrictId equals dic.DistrictId
                              join div in _db.Divisions on dic.DivisionId equals div.DivisionId
                              join con in _db.Countries on div.CountryId equals con.CountryId

                              select new
                              {
                                  con.CountryName,
                                  div.DivisionName,
                                  dic.DistrictName,
                                  upz.UpazilaName,
                                  unon.UnionName
                              }).ToList();

            return View();
        }
```

View

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>



<table class="">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Country</td>
            <td>Division</td>
            <td>District</td>
            <td>Upazila</td>
            <td>Union</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            @if (ViewBag.Unions != null)
            {

                foreach (var un in ViewBag.Unions)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@un.CountryName </td>
                        <td>@un.DivisionName</td>
                        <td>@un.DistrictName</td>
                        <td>@un.UpazilaName</td>
                        <td>@un.UnionName</td>
                    </tr>
                }

            }
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because ViewBag is a dynamic type dictionary. So each of your item in that collection are dynamic type. The compiler skips the type checking when you try to access a property of an dynamic type object, but it might fail in run time (***This is exactly one of the reason i am avoiding ViewBag/ViewData as much as possible***).

What you should be doing is, create a view model to represent this data and project to that in your LINQ expression

```
public class MyViewModel
{
  public string CountryName { set;get;}
  public string DivisionName  { set;get;}
  public string DistrictName { set;get;}
}
```

Now since you have a strongly typed class, you do not really need ViewBag to pass the data. You can directly pass the list of `MyViewModel` objects to the view.

```
var items = (from unon in _db.Unions
                  join upz in _db.Upazilas on unon.UpazilaId equals upz.UpazilaId
                  join dic in _db.Districts on upz.DistrictId equals dic.DistrictId
                  join div in _db.Divisions on dic.DivisionId equals div.DivisionId
                  join con in _db.Countries on div.CountryId equals con.CountryId   
              select new MyViewModel
                                   {
                                      CountryName = con.CountryName,
                                      DivisionName = div.DivisionName,
                                      DistrictName = dic.DistrictName        
                                   }).ToList();

 return View(items);
```

Now make sure your view is strongly typed to this collection type

```
@model List<MyViewModel>
<table class="table>
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
  <tr>
      <td>@item.CountryName</td>
      <td>@item.DivisionName</td>
      <td>@item.DistrictnName</td>
  </tr>
}
</table>
```

If you still want to use ViewBag to pass the data (but why ???), you can do that. Instead of passing the list of items to the view method, you can set it to view bag and access it in your razor view. Make sure to cast it to a list `MyViewModel` before you start looping the collection.

```
ViewBag.Items = items;
return View();
```

and in the view

```
<table class="table>
@foreach(var item in ViewBag.Items as List<MyViewModel>)
{
  <tr>
      <td>@item.CountryName</td>
      <td>@item.DivisionName</td>
      <td>@item.DistrictnName</td>
  </tr>
}
</table>
```

Comment: Your answer is correct. But I want to use anonymous object in ViewBag to pass data controller to view.

Comment: Yes you can use view bag to pass the data ( same as what you did in your original post). You need to Cast the ViewBag dictionary item to list of MyViewModel and that will give you intellisense for those property names.